# Timeout and Exception Function Getting Stuck

Tags: python, timeout, signals

I am polling data using a python 2.7.10 function that I want to timeout if a device takes too long to respond, or catch a RuntimeError if that device is not available. 
I am using this Timeout function:

```
class Timeout():
        class Timeout(Exception):
            pass
        def __init__(self, sec):
            self.sec = sec
        def __enter__(self):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.raise_timeout)
            signal.alarm(self.sec)
        def __exit__(self, *args):
            signal.alarm(0)
        def raise_timeout(self, *args):
            raise Timeout.Timeout()
```

This is my loop to make the data polls (Modbus) and catch the exceptions. This loop is called every 60 seconds:

```
def getDeviceTags(name, tag_data):
    global val_returns
    for tag in tag_data[name]:
        local_vals = []
        local_vals.append(name+"."+tag)
        try:
            with Timeout(3):
                value = modbus.read(str(name), str(tag))
                local_vals.append(str(value.value()))
        except RuntimeError:
            print("RuntimeError on " + str(name))
            local_vals.append(None)
        except Timeout.Timeout:
            print("Timeout on " + str(name))
            local_vals.append(None)
        val_returns.append(local_vals)
```

This will work for DAYS at a time with no issues, both RuntimeErrors and Timeouts being printed to the console, all data logged - GREAT.
However, recently its been getting stuck - and this is the only error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "working_one_min_back.py", line 161, in <module>
    job()
  File "working_one_min_back.py", line 79, in job
    getDeviceTags(str(key), data)
  File "working_one_min_back.py", line 57, in getDeviceTags
    print("RuntimeError on " + str(name))
  File "working_one_min_back.py", line 30, in raise_timeout
    raise Timeout.Timeout()
__main__.Timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s no guarantee that a “Python signal” isn’t delivered **after** a call to `alarm(0)`.  The actual (C) signal might *already* have been delivered, causing the Python handler to be invoked [a few bytecode instructions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.setcheckinterval) later.

If you call `signal.signal` from `__exit__`, any such pending signal is **discarded**, which usefully prevents mistaking it for the *next* one requested.  Using that to **restore** the handler to the value it had before the `Timeout` was created (as returned by the first `signal.signal` call) is a good idea anyway.  (Reset it **after** calling `alarm(0)` to prevent `SIG_DFL` from killing the process.)

In Python 3, such a call **delivers** any pending signals instead of discarding them, which is an improvement in that it prevents losing a signal just because the handler changed.  (This is no more documented than the Python 2 behavior, unfortunately.)  You can try to suppress such a late signal by setting an attribute in `__exit__` and ignoring any (Python) signal raised when it is set.

Of course, the signal could be delivered after `__exit__` begins execution and before the signal is discarded (or marked to be ignored).  You therefore have to handle an operation **both** completing and timing out, perhaps by having several assignments to a single variable that is then `append`ed in just one place.

Comment: This is helpful - so the Timeout exception is being thrown outside of my try/except logic, causing the program to freeze. Can you clarify how to unset the handler or ignore the signals  - what needs to be added to __exit__? Thanks.

Comment: @OscarAugustMenzer: The basic, good-citizen approach merely involves storing the value returned from your **existing** `signal` call and passing it to the same function **again** in `__exit__`.  Is it not clear how to do that?  (Don’t forget the issue of a completed job also timing out!)